# Bayesian updating with correlated data

Tags: bayesian, correlation, inference, autocorrelation, bayesian-network

I’m looking for some readings on the topic of correlation between data used for Bayesian inversion. There are a lot of discussions about the correlations between the parameters being updated i.e. $\mathbf{x}$, but I didn’t find much on the correlation between the data points, i.e. $\mathbf{y}$.

$$P(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{y}) \propto L(\mathbf{x})\times P(\mathbf{x})$$

The reason why I’m interested in that is because when working on health monitoring systems, multiple data sources are installed to establish the performance of a structural component. Now, this data is highly correlated. I think assuming the data points to be independent, we’re overestimating the information we gain from this data.

I’d be glad if someone could point out some good readings on a similar topic.

Comment: The data is correlated *for a reason*; it's a sign the Ys are dependent on some common variable. If you don't factor that in, the two datapoints are not conditionally independent - if the two systems are very similar, p(Y1|Y2) = 1 and vice versa.

Comment: Are we talking about the multivariate case, where you have more than on y-variable? Or about a repeated meassure y?

Comment: I'm talking about the multivariate case.

Let's say a single parameter, $x$, is being updated with three data points, $y_1$, $y_2$ and $y_3$, but the data points aren't i.i.d.s; they're correlated.

How does the correlation influence the updated estimates of $x$, as opposed to the case when they're iids?

Comment: If the three observations $y_1,y_2,y_3$ are correlated it means they are generated from a joint model and you should use the joint model to update the prior into the posterior. Bayesian analysis always requires the _full probabilistic model_ behind the data!

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an. Is there any reference for the same? I mean, how does the posterior obtained from the fully correlated data set differ from that obtained using the uncorrelated data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update from prior to posterior is given by
$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf y)\propto \pi(\theta) f(\mathbf y|\theta)=\pi(\theta) \underbrace{f(y_1,y_2,y_3|\theta)}_\text{joint density}$$
and
$$f(y_1,y_2,y_3|\theta)\ne f_1(y_1|\theta)f_2(y_2|\theta)f_3(y_3|\theta)$$
if $f_1,f_2,f_3$ denote the marginal densities of $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$, respectively.